# MS-Access get the list of products having a special indicator for all the multiple records of the product

Tags: sql, ms-access

I  had a stock data report which consists of various columns

- P.Num
- S.Loc
- Batch
- Del @ S.Loc
- Qty
- Price
- Value

report consists of multiple records for each product with a combination of "S.Loc" & "Batch".
Each record is having its own "qty", "price" & "value".

Here another column "Del @ S.loc" which having an entry "X" or empty.

"X" indicates that the product is deleted from the system records at the particular "S.Loc" & "Batch", for further transactions.

Now i need to identify/exclude the products having this "X" indicator items as completely deleted item, only when the same product is in another S.Loc also marked as "X". otherwise the product is available for any transaction in other Storage Locations.

I appreciate if some one help me in writing the query.

[image]

Comment: Why is Product5, S2, B a candidate for deletion?

Comment: Why did you tag with MySQL and SQLite if this be an Access/VBA question?

Comment: Product 5 is a candidate for deletion where it needs to be excluded from analysis.. because it is no where available in any other batches or storage locations.

Comment: Iam doing the analysis using access and trying to build an application using [PHP & MYSQL] or [PHP & SQLite]

Comment: Why is Product 3, S3, C a candidate for deletion?  You text description does not make very much clear.

Comment: Since the focus of this question is only the query, I removed all irrelevant tags.

Comment: Here if a product is having a deletion indicator at all locations, that product is no longer required for consumption.

if the product is having a deletion indicator at one storage location and no deletion indicators at other storage locations means that the product is to be considered for analysis.

Comment: i have to get the list of products which having the status ok and their total stock quantity and inventory value...
based on this list i have to make other analysis for inventory.

- Product3 & Product 5 will go for scrapping..

- stock in "Product2 S2 A" will be moved later to another storage location.
So still its available for accounting/inventory

Comment: To check the deletion, an indicator "X" is marked in fourth column named as "Del. @ S.Loc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select [P.Num]
from t
group by [P.Num]
having min([Del @ S.Loc]) = 'X' and max([Del @ S.Loc]) = 'X';
```

If you want the original records, you can `join` this back to the original data.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help..
This query is collecting the Product 2 also which i don't need..because it is not having "X" marks in its other records.

Comment: the query given by you is working only when the "X" is replaced by "1" and the empty cell value replaced by "0".

But its not possible for me to replace them as the data is linked from another db.

please find me a a solution ..

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. I found the answer now..

    SELECT Material,
    SUM(Qty) as Total_Quantity,
    avg(Price) as Avg_price,
    SUM(Value) as Inventory_Value
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Material
    HAVING COUNT(Material) = COUNT(Del_Sloc);